# Select exact number of table td after a radiobutton is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multistep form, where in one step I select the whole number (1–X) with which I can work in the next step. In the next step I have a table of days of a week (I only show a shortened version here). Some of the cells contain radiobuttons.

What I want to do is: if I select one of the radiobuttons I need to add a class to the exact number of column TD which are below this one (where I checked the radio).
Here is an example of the table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Úterý<br />06.12.2011</th>
           <th>Středa<br />07.12.2011</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>08:00</td>
            <td><div class="form-item" id="edit-datetime-worker-wrapper">
                <label class="option" for="edit-datetime-worker">
                <input type="radio" id="edit-datetime-worker" name="datetime_worker" value="2011-12-06T08:00:00::3"   class="form-radio" />
                <span>6. 12. 2011 – 08:00</span></label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td><div class="form-item" id="edit-datetime-worker-11-wrapper">
                <label class="option" for="edit-datetime-worker-11">
                <input type="radio" id="edit-datetime-worker-11" name="datetime_worker" value="2011-12-07T08:00:00::3"   class="form-radio" />
                <span>7. 12. 2011 – 08:00</span></label>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td>08:30</td>
            <td><div class="form-item" id="edit-datetime-worker-1-wrapper"></div></td>
            <td><div class="form-item" id="edit-datetime-worker-12-wrapper">
                <label class="option" for="edit-datetime-worker-12">
                <input type="radio" id="edit-datetime-worker-12" name="datetime_worker" value="2011-12-07T08:30:00::3"   class="form-radio" />
                <span>7. 12. 2011 – 08:30</span></label>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>09:00</td>
            <td><div class="form-item" id="edit-datetime-worker-2-wrapper">
                <label class="option" for="edit-datetime-worker-2">
                <input type="radio" id="edit-datetime-worker-2" name="datetime_worker" value="2011-12-06T09:00:00::3"   class="form-radio" />
                <span>6. 12. 2011 – 09:00</span></label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td><div class="form-item" id="edit-datetime-worker-13-wrapper">
                <label class="option" for="edit-datetime-worker-13">
                <input type="radio" id="edit-datetime-worker-13" name="datetime_worker" value="2011-12-07T09:00:00::3"   class="form-radio" />
                <span>7. 12. 2011 – 09:00</span></label>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

From the previous step I have a number, say 2. So I check the first radio button in the second column (středa 7. 12. 2011) and I need to add a class to the cell below (or div in it).

How can I achieve this? I'm really a noob in JS. :(
If you need additional information, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: What does the previous step look like? My first thought would be to do something along the line of `$("#edit-datetime-worker-"+NUMBERFROM PREVIOUSSTEP).attr("checked","checked");`. This would check the radiobutton with the number from the previous step. In the same way you could add a CSS class: `$("#edit-datetime-worker-"+NUMBERFROM PREVIOUSSTEP).addClass("NEWCSSCLASS");`.

Comment: In the previous step, there user selects an act. Every act needs different timespan - that is the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you want to highlight a column depending on which radio button is selected? http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/fYqME/

You can make use of `.index()` to determine which column is selected, and then use `:nth-child()` to select the actual td in the column.

```
$('input:radio').change(function() {
    var i = $(this).parent().index() + (1);
    $('td').removeClass('highlight');
    $('td:nth-child(' + i + ')').addClass('highlight');
});
```

**Updated.** Looks more complicated than it needs to be.  If you can clarify your functional needs, we can simplify the code.  But if that cannot be done, here's the updated code.  `var num = 2` is the amount of cells to highlight. http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/fYqME/1/

```
$('input:radio').change(function() {
    var num = 2;
    var col = $(this).closest('td').index() + 1;
    var row = $(this).closest('tr').index();

    var tds = $('td:nth-child(' + col + ')');
    tds = tds.slice(row,row+num);

    $('td').removeClass('highlight');
    tds.addClass('highlight');
});
```

Comment: Yes, something like that. But with the diferrence, I don't want to higlight the whole collumn, but only the specified numebr of TDs bellow the td with selected radiobutton. here is an image of highlighted table from above code. http://www.studioillek.cz/download/table-highlight.png

Comment: Thank you a lot. On the JS Fiddle preview the script is making exactly what I need. When I copy the script to my develop site – its not doing anything. :/ In error console I've **$(this).closest is not a function**, but its should not be the problem, because I've another script which is doing some other thing after the radio is selected and this one is working (and uses .closest too). I even try to delete my script and execute only your function, but with no avail.

Comment: Ok. I just found the problem. I've only jquery v. 1.3.2 - and can't updated it. Its posible to rewrite this code to work using this version?

Comment: OK. I just managed to update my drupal site to 1.7.1. Now its working like a charm. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 0):

just add a unique id(number) for both the radio button and the  in which the radio button is present. For e.g.

```
<td id=1><div class="form-item" id="edit-datetime-worker-wrapper">
         <label class="option" for="edit-datetime-worker">
         <input type="radio" id="edit-datetime-worker-1" name="datetime_worker" value="2011-12-06T08:00:00::3"   class="form-radio" />
          <span>6. 12. 2011 – 08:00</span></label>
          </div>
</td>
```

Note that unique id for the  **is 1** and the same for radio button id="edit-datetime-worker-**1**".
 Now you can get the unique number of the radio button using the ***getattribute()*** function and match that number with the  and you can now add class to the  when you click on the corresponding radio button.