# jquery script not working under chrome, safari and partially opera, FF is ok

Tags: javascript, jquery

today I have been asking here for help with this [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397096/select-exact-number-of-table-td-after-a-radiobutton-is-checked).

It was successfully done – thanks again to RKW.

I've merge the code with my previous one, and everthing seems working well – under FF. But now, I've tryed it under Chrome, Safari (mac) and Opera.
In Chrome and Safari the script isn't doing enything at all (and the error console stay clear). Under opera only the first part is working – the class active is added.

Any suggestions?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').focus(function() { /* add class active to parent div */
        $('div').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass('active');
        $(this).closest("div").addClass('active');
    });

    $('input:radio').focus(function() { /* add class highlight to specified tds in one column */
        var num = 2;
        var col = $(this).closest('td').index() + 1;
        var row = $(this).closest('tr').index();

        var tds = $('td:nth-child(' + col + ')');
        tds = tds.slice(row,row+num);

        $('td').removeClass('highlight');
        tds.addClass('highlight');
    });
});
```

Comment: You should post your html or even a better a jsfiddle. It is really hard to guess what your html structure is based on your javascript.

Comment: There is a link to my previous post, where is the html. I try to not post too many duplicate content...

Comment: You will get better/faster answers if you post what is relevant in the question. People don't like clicking through and reading other answers just to understand your current question.

Comment: Given the layout of the HTML you provided, since the only inputs are radio buttons, you can place all that code in input:radio or input

Comment: mrtsherman: thank you for your advice. I'm new to this site – iI've lot to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure what you are trying to do with your highlight class (as in how/what it should highlight) however, there are a few changes you need to make to properly apply the classes to the divs.

Instead of using .focus(), you'll want to use:

```
$('input').click(function()
```

and

```
$('input:radio').focus(function()
```

One note about input:radio is that it will have to use jQuery's engine to find the radio buttons since it is not a standard CSS2/3 selector. If speed of execution is crucial, use Thiago Santos' type='radio' (since CSS understands this, so will your browser).

The other thing I've changed is this:

```
$('div').removeClass('active');
```

Since it didn't find the divs in chrome, however to do the same thing in a page when I was messing with transforms, I found all the elements that used the .active class and removed them from all elements before setting $(this) element with the tag. Changing it to:

```
$('.active').removeClass('active');
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/588qG/2/)

I also noticed you were using CSS' `nth-child`, please note that this does not work for IE8 or less (or IE9 in quirks mode).

Comment: Thank for extensive answer. It is working now in Chrome and safari. But the opera behaves still the same. the firt part is executed, the second one not - but its maybe related to some drupal and jquery dislike. Marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

On the second part, try changing:

```
$("input:radio")...
```

to

```
$("input[type='radio']")...
```

Comment: too bad.. what I did was a guess.. but I think you should add a sample jsfiddle so ppl can understand better what's the problem